# JMockit @Tested field with Specific Constructor

Tags: unit-testing, jmockit

I am trying to mock a class with JMockit 1.45.
Since the `Deencapsulation.setField` method is removed, I can´t set a private field value. So I am looking for finding a way to set the private field value while the class is initiated. I have added a additional Constructor to set a private field value. But, I dont´t find a way to get a propery setted instance with `@Tested` annotation with a speicific Constructor. Is there any other way to do it?

the "long maxSizeByte" should be set by Configuration and I need to test if the method is working in various values.

Code Sample Production Class

```
public class MagazineFetcher {  

    @EJB private StatisticDAO statisticDao;

    // configs
    private long maxSizeByte;

    public MagazineFetcher() {
        this(ProjectConfig.getCdsMaxChannelSizeByte());
    }
    // This constructor is adde for a testcase to set the private value
    public MagazineFetcher(long maxSizeByte) {
        this.maxSizeByte = maxSizeByte;
    }

    // using maxSizeByte field for a calcuation and validation      
    public void doSomething(){
    }
}
```

Test Case

```
public class MagazineFetcherTest {
    @Injectable private StatisticDAO statisticDao;

    @Tested private MagazineFetcher magazineFetcher ;

    @Test
    public void testInvalidImportFile() throws Exception {

        magazineFetcher.doSomething();
    }
}
```

It seems `@Tested private MagazineFetcher magazineFetcher` instantiated by only Default Constructor. I am looking for the way to initiated by another constructor. When I simply `MagazineFetcher magazineFetcher = new MagazineFetcher(100 * 1024)` then I get a instance that `statisticDao` is not injected.

Comment: Did you try to specify a `long maxSizeByte` value to be injected into the `@Tested` object. The same way you already inject the DAO...

Comment: @ Rogério According to JMockit Tutorial, @Injectable will work for remaining uninitialized fields. [@Injectable tutorial](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Mocking.html#tested) "the tested class is initialized with the chosen constructor, its remaining uninitialized non-final instance fields are considered for injection."  the fields are already initialized by constructor. however, I have tried just now. it is not injected.

Comment: I got an idea. I can add a getter method for the `long maxSizeByte` and refactor the tested(MagazineFetcher) class to refer only the getter method instead of accessing the field directly. Then I can facke the getter method. I need to use Mocking and Facking API for a test again. It might not a good idea. but, I don´t find any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I dont´t want to change any production code for running a JMockit testcase. But I had to add a method to mock it. I would appreciate to get any better idea.

```
public class MagazineFetcher {  

    @EJB private StatisticDAO statisticDao;

    // configs
    private long maxSizeByte;

    // Method is added only for Testcase
    long getMaxSizeByte() { return maxSizeByte;  }

    public MagazineFetcher() {
        maxSizeByte = ProjectConfig.getCdsMaxChannelSizeByte();
    }
    // No need to add a constructor
    // public MagazineFetcher(long maxSizeByte) {
    //  this.maxSizeByte = maxSizeByte;
    // }

    public void doSomething(){
        // using maxSizeByte field is replaced by getMaxSizeByte() 
        if ( ... < getMaxSizeByte() ) 
            ....
    }
}
```

Test Case

```
public class MagazineFetcherTest {
    @Injectable private StatisticDAO statisticDao;

    @Tested private MagazineFetcher magazineFetcher ;

    @Test
    public void testInvalidImportFile() throws Exception {

        new MockUp<MagazineFetcher>(){
            @Mock
            long getMaxSizeByte() {
                return 1024 * 1024 * 250;
            }
        };

        magazineFetcher.doSomething();
    }
}
```